# Check condition before changing post status in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a form in the front end which enables users to submit posts. These posts are by default saved as pending. It can only set to publish by the admin. Before publishing certain conditions are to be checked before its set as published.

If the condition is true set post status as publish. If not set it as pending. What is the appropriate action hook to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

look here, there is 6 hooks than you can use for that :
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L4058

just take care that the values that you use in your condition can also be change on this hooks then you have to test where you have the values you need.